# 2-D motion Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, projectile

> A bottle dropped from a balloon reaches the ground in 20 s. Determine the height of the
>   balloon if (a) it was at rest in the air and (b) it was rising with a speed of 50 m/s when the
>   bottle was dropped. answer: (a) 1.96 km, (b) 0.96 km

To answer a), I knew I had to find final velocity before finding height so I used:

Vf = Vi + a*t

I set it up as Vf = 0 + 9.8m/s^2 * 20s and got Vf = 196 m/s.

Then I used x = (Vi + Vf)/ 2 * t and got 1960m which is of course 1.96km.

I understand that for b) Vi will be 50m/s however I have not been able to get an answer even close to the one above (0.96km). I know that whatever answer I get will need to added to 1960m as that was the height when the bottle was dropped and I assume the total height is that + whatever the height the balloon was as it kept going upward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful with the second case, as the height of 1980 m **isn't the height when the bottle was dropped** (this is the thing you want to calculate it in the first place). I think that's where your confusion comes from, so be careful when using the concepts. I suggest you redo the calculations carefully and you should be able to get the result (i.e. check signs, multiplications, powers, etc.). I already confirmed you can arrive to the result, so you don't have to worry the text is wrong.

I also suggest that for problems when you already have the time and initial velocity, you work instead with the other acceleration formula: $x=v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$. I know usually students are not encouraged to use this one, but personally I think it's way easier since you can directly calculate distances without resorting to intermediate formulas (which can lead to errors).

Try to work on it and tell me if you have any further trouble.

Comment: Hi, using the formula as: x = 50(20) + .5(-9.8)(20^2) I got -960m as an answer however it is negative. I did manage to find it another way but not sure if it's a legitimate method or if I was just simply lucky:

I used vf = 50 + 9.8(20) and got 246. I subtracted 196 (final velocity from part a) to get 50. Using x = (vi + vf)/2 * t, I did (50 + 50)/2 * 20 and got 1000. I subtracted 1960 by 1000 and got 960. Not sure if this is an actual method or if it was just a result of me messing the values around to find the correct answer.

Comment: It's correct since you're measuring the distance the bottle dropped downwards, so you expect the distance to be negative from the position where it was dropped. 
If you really want it to be positive you could use the more general expression (sorry I forgot to add it): $x=x_0+V_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$. Setting $x=0$ (the ground), now your height would be $x_0$ and your answer should be immediatly positive.

Comment: And for the other method, I'm pretty sure it just a lucky guess since you already knew the answer. For example, there's no reason why you should substract 196 from 246 as the questions are completely unrrelated, nor is correct to substract 1960 from 1000. How would you know to do this if you didn't already know the answer? My suggestion is to be careful about what values and formulas you're using, and as long as everything is right, the math should guide you to the final answer.